# What does 即 mean in ...Google在ICML文中描述的非常清晰，即在每次SGD时...?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

According to [the top answer over 知乎](https://www.zhihu.com/question/38102762) on the question *深度学习中 Batch Normalization为什么效果好？*:

> 顾名思义，batch normalization嘛，就是“批规范化”咯。Google在ICML文中描述的非常清晰，**即**在每次SGD时，通过mini-batch来对相应的activation做规范化操作，使得结果（输出信号各个维度）的均值为0，方差为1.

What does the 即 mean? Does this function as `be`? In this case, is it necessary to use 即, instead of 在每次SGD时, and also why is 即 preferred to other words that mean `be`, such as 是，为, etc...?

Comment: 即 here is short for 即是 (namely; that is to say; **to be specific**)

Comment: @TangHo Oh I see. Could you write it as your answer, possibly with some more explanation? Why is 即 usually preferred to 即是?

Comment: = " i.e. " in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

即 itself can mean "equal".  For example: '五人**即**一伍' (Five men **equal** one unit)

~ *you can replace 即 (equal) with 為(be), For example:  '五人**為**一伍' (Five men **is** one unit)*

But 即 can be short for 即是 (namely; that is to say; to be specific)

Example:

[1. 軍隊將士兵分伍] [2. **即**] [3.每五人組成一個單位]

[1. Amy divides soldiers into 伍] [2. **to be specific** ] [3. Every five people become one unit]

[1. general statement] [2. **to be specific**] [3. detail description]

Comment: "即 itself can mean "equal" Can you provide the source of this claim? I'm quiet interested in this. Thanks.

Comment: 即 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1055/ - [2] [adv] namely; exactly; precisely. 'A 即 B' means 'A is exactly the same as B' -- '五人即一伍' means 'five men is precisely one unit'

Comment: As you can see, 即 contains a few meanings. some of them are extension of the basic meanings of " immediately(adv); approach(v)"

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes I see that 即 varies between "is" and "like" so "equal" translation is a possibility for this hanzi.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "be"(is/am/are/was/were) to help you to understand the "即"
It helps to display the same content(maybe is a explanation or a defination) of the front word/sentence(it depends the situation)

Comment: And “即” was often used to in writting . In the oral situation,it rarely use.Maybe when you give a seriously academic speech to use "即" after a term and then explain it or define it.
Format:
some term  ， 即details