# What do 即 (jí) and 已 (yǐ) do in the sentence 病征在成年早期即已显露 ("symptoms become visible at early adulthood")?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In a document about [边缘性人格障碍](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%BE%B9%E7%BC%98%E6%80%A7%E4%BA%BA%E6%A0%BC%E9%9A%9C%E7%A2%8D) (biānyuán xìng réngé zhàng'ài) = "Borderline Personality Disorder", we have the following sentence:

> 病征在成年早期即已显露，但随年龄增长趋于缓和或稳定。
>   <sub>Bìngzhēng zài chéngnián zǎoqí jí yǐ xiǎnlù, dàn suí niánlíng zēngzhǎng qū yú huǎnhé huò wěndìng.</sub>

I translate this to:

> Symptoms become visible at early adulthood, but with age they have an increasing tendency to alleviate or stabilize.

I think it's a reasonably accurate translation.  ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.cn/#zh-CN/en/%E7%97%85%E5%BE%81%E5%9C%A8%E6%88%90%E5%B9%B4%E6%97%A9%E6%9C%9F%E5%8D%B3%E5%B7%B2%E6%98%BE%E9%9C%B2%EF%BC%8C%E4%BD%86%E9%9A%8F%E5%B9%B4%E9%BE%84%E5%A2%9E%E9%95%BF%E8%B6%8B%E4%BA%8E%E7%BC%93%E5%92%8C%E6%88%96%E7%A8%B3%E5%AE%9A%E3%80%82) gives a translation that's much the same: "Symptoms are revealed early in adulthood, but tend to ease or stabilize with age.")

What I'm confused about is the use of

- [即](http://dict.cn/%E5%8D%B3) (jí), which means something like "namely" (also mentioned in [What does 即 mean in this sentence?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/25995/what-does-%E5%8D%B3-mean-in-this-sentence)), but I don't think that makes sense here, and
- [已](http://dict.cn/%E5%B7%B2) (yǐ), which means something like "already".

Neither of these makes sense to me in this context.

**Question**: What do 即 and 已 do in the sentence 病征在成年早期即已显露?

There's a few examples of 即已 used together on [YouDao](http://youdao.com/w/eng/%E5%8D%B3%E5%B7%B2/#keyfrom=dict2.index), but I don't see how they help.

Comment: 即已=已经 iciba：自儿童时起即已开始有严格的课程设置.early舒伯特的技巧在他十分年轻时即已达到了顶峰.while quite young 这个问题归根到底是一种挑战,这种挑战自从有了国际关系即已存在"as old as",

Comment: 即 also carries a meaning of causation or strong correlation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

即 in this context means 即刻: "immediately; at once; instantly"

已 = already; had

即已 = had immediately

即已显露= had immediately shown

Edit:

就 can also means "immediately"

- 黎明[**即**]起 = Wake up [**as soon as**] dawn arrives
- 黎明[**就**]起床 = wake up [**as soon as**] dawn arrives

Answer (score 2):

> 病征在成年早期即已显露

即 here means 就. It means this sense:

[image]

So, 病征在成年早期即已显露 is equal to say 病征在成年早期就已显露.

Comment: 成年早期即已显露= it appeared as soon as 成年早期 arrived;    成年早期就已显露 = it already appeared as early as 成年早期

Comment: People should read this discussion on the many meanings of 就  here http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/phorum/read.php?7,138618,page=1

Answer (score 2):

即已 = 就已经

病征在成年早期即已（就已经）显露，
Symptoms are already apparent in early adulthood
但随年龄增长趋于缓和或稳定。
but with age tend to moderate or stabilize.